# How to get help of PyGTK methods?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, docstring

in pygtk when I set the label `mylabel = gtk.Label("Hello World!")` I can get the string of label from it by `mylabel.get()` method. but in python interpreter I can't get the docstring of this method: `help(gtk.Label.get)`. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that what you wanted to ask was answered by @DonQuestion already... however if you truly just wanted to ask why `help(gtk.Label.get)` doesn't return a help... the answer is actually very simple: because the `get` method in the `Label` object lacks a docstring in the source code. :)

In fact the call to `help` doesn't generate an error, just an empty answer.

Comment: Do you know how can I read the source code of gtk.Label.get() method? In most of the library of python, I can get into the source code of them except pygtk!

Comment: @Khajavi - in a python shell: `import gtk; gtk` will print the location of the module. However most of the functionality of gtk is implemented in C, so you will find very little python code there, and mostly `.so` libraries...

Comment: Aha! and so because of this, there isn't any docstring for this library? In PyDev Eclipse, most of library have document in code-completion, except pygtk and it is annoying me a lot. Is it true?

Comment: @Khajavi - I'm not an expert on the subject so I can't really say for sure. My understanding is that _there are ways_ to bind C libraries to python in such a way that you will get basic introspection (I believe this can be done with [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html), for example [search the page for "introspection"]) but again: my knowledge on the subject is very limited and I might be wrong! :)

Answer (score 3):

Because the method `gtk.Label.get` is an object itself, and has some attributes. The builtin function `help` looks the `__doc__` attribute and some other dictionaries of the object and the Class of the object up and returns them (formatted). You could do a `help(help)` for example! ;-) so `help(gtk.Label.get)` returns the attribute "`__doc__`" of the method/object `gtk.Label.get` and some other information gathered by class-introspection. It **doesn't** give you a help on the **actual values** of your `gtk.Label` **instance**.

Comment: Only reading your answer made me really understand the question... I would have never imagined the OP intended to use `help` for _that_ purpose! :o

Comment: My question was very vague ;) I correct it now. I want to know why I can't get docstring of gtk.label.get() method!

Comment: You do get the get-method doc-string. It just happens to be empty.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use ipython's [dynamic object information](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.12/interactive/reference.html#dynamic-object-information) is quite helpful when playing with some library in the interpreter or when debugging some code.

Aside from that, if you're using linux, installing the `pygtk` documentation package is also very helpful because it integrates nicely with [`devhelp`](http://live.gnome.org/devhelp), a tool that lets you browse and search the documentation easily.

Comment: I'am using Devhelp, and I'm working with pygtk documention in it, when I search about gtk.Label.get() method, there isn't any documentation! Do you know why?

Comment: @Khajavi That's because it's a deprecated method at least since gtk 2.6 as you can see [here](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/GtkLabel.html#gtk-label-get). `gtk.Label.get_text` or `gtk.Label.get_label` should be used instead.

Comment: Learning pygtk with pygtktutorial is amazing :D Very great answer. You helped me very well! It was confusing me so much.